# SDL draws images blurred without scaling

Tags: c++, image, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on a project in C++ using SDL (Simple Directmedia Layer) but when I draw a SDL_Texture to the screen it's blurred eventhough it is not scaled.

How the image is loaded:

```
SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load("image.png");
SDL_Texture* gImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface);
```

How the image is drawn to the screen:

```
SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, width, height };
SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gImage , NULL, &renderQuad );
```

See image, left is in the program and right is the original:

[image]

Is there a parameter a forgot to set? And is it normal that SDL does this?

I'm using SDL 2.0 32-bit on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine.

Comment: Looks like the image has been antialiased.

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the Render Scale Quality hint. More info here: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9500

Comment: Are you using any `SDL_GL_*` functions anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Oli414 Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: @YassineHoussni unfortunately I haven't found a solution :-/

Comment: @Oli414 I'm starting to think that there is no solution, but if I find it I will post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Ahead of your call to SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface try calling:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0");
```

According to [SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY) this should affect how SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface calls interpolate the surface. "0" should result in nearest neighbour removing the blurring effect you are seeing.

Comment: Already tried this, doesn't change anything. Probably because the textures are not scaled. Changing it to another value doesn't change anything either.